# How would you make a button with CSS to not be clickable outside the button?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

[image]

I have created some buttons to be stacked on each other. However, the where it is highlighted blue I can still click. Is there a way to make it only clickable in the button itself?

Here is my CSS code so far

```
.buttons .button{  
  background-color: #041e42; 
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-right: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Here is the React.js code below

```
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="header">
        <h1> Software  </h1>
        <h1>Summer 2022 </h1>
        <h1> Section 01 </h1>
        <h1> Team 2 </h1>
      </div>
      <div className="buttons">
        <Link to="/">
          <button className="button">button 1</button>
        </Link>

        <Link to="/">
          <button className="button">button 2</button>
        </Link>

        <Link to="/PersonalAbout/page2">
          <button className="button">button 3</button>
        </Link>

        <Link to="/">
          <button className="button"> button 4</button>
        </Link>

        <Link to="/">
          <button className="button">button 5</button>
        </Link>

        <Link to="/">
          <button className="button">button 6</button>
        </Link>

        <Link to="/">
          <button className="button">button 7</button>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
    // </div>


  )
}
```

Comment: Pls post the appropriate HTML code as well which will help us better understand the structure of your HTML and help you better.

Comment: Can you please provide your HTML? Any JS you're using as well.

Comment: Added the JSX code

Comment: What are your `Link` components? You're actually not hovering over the buttons in the image, you're hovering over the`Link` component. You shouldn't need both a button and a `Link`.

Answer (score 0):

because you have embedded your buttons in Link tags  that works like anchor tags(in React), So actually your link tags have a width of 100% by default. the solution for this problem is either you give a width and height to the anchor tag (giving style to anchor tags works same for Link tag in react) and contain the button inside covering full parent element i.e the link tag in this case or you can place your link tags inside your button tags like:

```html
 
          <button className="button">
          <Link to="/">button 1 </Link>
          </button>
```

Comment: Yes, it was the link tag in react. Fixed it yesterday. Thank you for the reply nonetheless though.

Comment: Great. you can vote my answer if it helped you anyway. Thankyou